# html5 microdata strategy for a planned activity (not physical)

Tags: seo, html5, microdata

I try to put microdata in a leisure club's planning, which propose various activities (drawing, yoga, english for kids...). My problem is with those weekly activities as microdata event does'nt propose a convenient way to tag them.

My question is simple do you think this :

```
<li itemscop itemtype="https://schema.org/PlayAction">
    <a href="url/19-drawing" title="drawing" itemprop="url">
        <strong itemprop="name">Drawing</strong>
    </a>
    <div itemscop itemType="http://schema.org/ScheduleAction">
        <time itemprop="scheduleTime" datetime="Fr 12:15-13:15">12:15 - 13-15</time>
    </div>
</li>
```

is correct ? (I want to say "Enjoy drawing every friday from 12:15 to 13:15".)

I mean are the use of PlayAction for a non physical activity, the nesting with ScheduleAction and finally the use of a datetime format like OpeningHours a good way (from a google POV) to use microdatas ?

Thanks you

Comment: [Cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26251529/1591669).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some notes about your markup:

- This HTML nesting has no effect on the Microdata parsing. You *have* to use a property if you want to denote a relationship between the two items.
- The `time` element can’t have a value like "Fr 12:15-13:15" (although schema.org’s documentation has similar examples; see [my issue](https://github.com/rvguha/schemaorg/issues/143)). You could use the `data` element or the `meta` element (yes, [even in the `body`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55133/17633)) instead.
- You might want to use the [`http` variant of schema.org URIs](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/68741/17633) in all cases.

About your use of schema.org types:

I don’t think your usage of the `ScheduleAction` type is appropriate. It’s an [`Action`](http://schema.org/Action), so it can be used for the *act* of scheduling something (e.g., "John scheduled an event"), and not for the *result* of this action. As the result here is an event, you should use the [`Event` type](http://schema.org/Event) (or one of its sub-types, e.g. for drawings maybe [`VisualArtsEvent`](http://schema.org/VisualArtsEvent)).

If you want to use an Action type for the drawing activity, you should probably use [`DrawAction`](http://schema.org/DrawAction) instead of [`PlayAction`](http://schema.org/PlayAction). However, do you really need it in the first place? Using only an `Event` item might be sufficient for your case.

As [described in my answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24700033/1591669) (which Stephen Ostermiller [referenced here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/69880/17633), too), you can’t declare recurring events with schema.org. While ISO 8601 seems to define a syntax for [repeating intervals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Repeating_intervals), schema.org defines that each `Event` item is for "an event", not several ones.

So you have to explicitly provide a separate `Event` item for each date/event (or change the date if you use always the same page and don’t archive older dates), or no date at all (i.e., only for humans in the HTML, but not in the Microdata).

Answer (score 0):

At [How to mark up recurring events with Schema.org for Google?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685541/how-to-mark-up-recurring-events-with-schema-org-for-google) [unor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1591669/unor) says:

Currently, there is only the solution to create separate `Event` items for each event, as described in [its definition](http://schema.org/Event):

> Repeated events may be structured as separate Event objects.

Related links:

- Mailing list thread: [Proper schema.org markup of repeating / recurring events?](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/2011Dec/thread.html#msg60)
- Wiki page: [WebSchemas/RepeatingEvents](http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas/RepeatingEvents)
- Issue: [Schema.org should say how to describe repeating events](http://www.w3.org/2011/webschema/track/issues/11)

In the mentioned thread, [Martin Hepp lists advantages](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/2011Dec/0062.html) of creating separate `Event` items for *each* single event:

- easier for consumers to query the data when each date is set explicitly
- you can model exceptions (cancelled, rescheduled or delayed events)