# Schema links and HTTPS

Tags: url, https, microdata, security-certificate

In the process of moving to 100% HTTPS on a site, I performed a site-wide search for `http://` in an effort to find potential problems. One common class of instances included [**schema**](https://schema.org/) links (certainly there is a more proper way to say this), i.e.

`<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">`

My first instinct is to change these to `https://`, just as one might with intra-site links. However, if you request either of the URLs mentioned above using HTTPS, you are automatically redirected (307 Temporary Redirect) to the same URL with `http://` (FF 38). As well, I have yet to see any mixed-content warnings as a result of having `http://`.

**With that in mind**

- Should I change these instances of `http://` to `https://`?
- Will [**W3C**](https://validator.w3.org/) support HTTPS for these resources?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are no resources which get usually accessed by the browser but simply a fancy way to declare a name space, i.e. all SVG images share the same XML name space which is defined by the URL and same with xlink. This means you should treat any of these xmlns just as some kind of special string and leave them unchanged.

Comment: As an additional note, the same goes for Schema.org and other machine/graph/meta namespaces: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71857/schema-org-itemtype-identifier-should-it-use-relative-urls-or-https-links